# Getting div contents in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html

Inside proper angular controllers etc.

HTML looks like this:

```
<div ng-model="userId">SomeUser</div>
```

angular looks like

```
$scope.loginRecieved = function () {
    var something = $scope.userId;
    window.alert(something);
}
```

The alert displays undefined. How do I get the contents of the div? Should note that I don't need this to be a div explicitly. I just have a Razor MVC function that only operates within the HTML view and can't be referenced in the script.js file.

Comment: On a higher level what is it you are needing that isn't being sent to the view from your data model? `Razor` doesn't tell us much since it runs on server

Comment: if you *really* want to do it this way (not recommended), I would start by researching [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). however, this seems like a bad way to do things; can you give a bit more of an example of what you are trying to get from the server to the client?  This is definitely feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me.